# preg_replace_callback regex syntax incorrect

Tags: php, regex, magento, callback, preg-replace

While I was searching for Magento turning on the sql query logging, I found a post with modification to Magento's core `query` function as below:

```
public function query($sql, $bind = array())
{
$this->_debugTimer();
try {
$sql = (string)$sql;
if (strpos($sql, ':') !== false || strpos($sql, '?') !== false) {
$this->_bindParams = $bind;
$sql = preg_replace_callback('#(([\'"])((2)|((.*?[^\])2)))#', array($this, 'proccessBindCallback'), $sql);
$bind = $this->_bindParams;
}
$code = 'SQL: ' . $sql . "rn";
if ($bind) {
$code .= 'BIND: ' . print_r($bind, true) . "rn";
}
$this->_debugWriteToFile("[".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."] ".$code);
$result = parent::query($sql, $bind);
}
catch (Exception $e) {
$this->_debugStat(self::DEBUG_QUERY, $sql, $bind);
$this->_debugException($e);
}
$this->_debugStat(self::DEBUG_QUERY, $sql, $bind, $result);
return $result;
}
```

What I don't get is why `preg_replace_callback` is needed here and what is the issue in the line containing `preg_replace_callback` in syntax when I put the above code in my editor it shows broken quote highlight ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Escape the single quote. See the color highlighting here? `['"]` that single quote closes your PHP string encapsulation.

Comment: You are right about that, but after this if I run my code it throws error in log `unexpected "["` in the same line.

Comment: If you have Magento source handy with you try this putting in your lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php replace the existing `query` function with the above one and then run the Magento homepage. You will know what error I am getting.

Comment: I don't have Magento. This `[^\]` seems incorrect to me though, that character class is never being closed, shouldn't produce a PHP syntax error though.. This is your exact code now?

Comment: I've no idea of what you're trying to do you so much (unclosed) groups in your regex. You may want to read a bit more about regex. also `\]`is making the character class not close properly.

Comment: This has way too many parenthesis for it to be legible, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have mistake in regexp near [^\], this is right

```
'#(([\'"])((2)|((.*?[^\\])2)))#'
```

for php string you also need escape some characters

```
   $re = "/#(([\\'\"])((2)|((.*?[^\\\\])2)))#/";  
   $str = "";` 
   preg_match($re, $str, $matches);
```

I offen use https://regex101.com/ for check and debug regexp.

Comment: This works thanks for your answer.